# "Схлопнуть" попарно одинаковые строки в массиве

Tags: c#

Как удалить из массива строк, одинаковые строки (попарно).

То есть если 3 одинаковые строки в массивы то удаляются 2 а 3 остается.

Мне это нужно для реализации метода Жигалкина на C#.

```
string[] arrayWord = temp.Split(new char[] { '\u2295' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = arrayWord.Distinct();
```

Пытался так удалить дубликаты но выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите на рисунке не выводиться строка. А должна вывестись. Она должна быть такая как и перед этим только за место x4x3x2x1 x4x3x1 x4x2x1 x4x1 x3x2x1 x3x1 x4x3x2x1 должна вывестись эта же строка только без x4x3x2x1 так как их парное количество и они должны удалится.

Comment: Как вы выводите `result`?

Comment: Так перепишите: `var result = string.Join(" ", arrayWord.Distinct());`

Comment: @АндрейNOP похоже тут `Distinct()` не подойдет, нужно удалять "попарно". Т.е если есть четное число вхождений - их все удалять (операция "сокращение")

Comment: @AGS17, ну с этим, возможно, автор и сам разберется, как видно по картинке, ему не понятно как вообще `IEnumerable` вывести, у него виден там результат `result.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (и проблема удаления попарно теперь и проблема вывода теперь решена):

```
string[] source = new[] {
    "asdf",
    "asdf1",
    "asdf",
    "123",
    "1234",
    "123",
    "123",
};

// Для наглядности чего сколько
source.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).Dump();

var result = source.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                   .Where(x => x.Count % 2 == 0)
                   .Select(x => x.Value);


foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавьте `.ToArray()` по вкусу, если не привыкли работать с `IEnumerable`

---

Updated В комментариях @AGS17 подсказал, как сократить запись:

```
var result = source.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Where(x => x.Count() % 2 != 0)
                   .Select(x => x.Key);
```

(И условие должно быть `!=`, а не `==`)

Comment: В таске висит ремарка "попарно".  Полагаю, `asdf` тут быть не должно

Comment: Ах, у автора вообще проблема в другом, он не знает как вывести список...

Comment: Переделал с учётом обоих проблем. Многословно правда получилось, но вроде не упростить.

Comment: Все равно не выводит почему то. Может свой MessageBox писать.

Comment: @SergeyLytvynenko Ага, значит у вас проблема не с подсчётом, а с выводом, а мы-то тут гадаем ) Я писал вывод с расчётом на консольное приложение, а у вас какой-то GUI проект, верно? Если так - заменяйте `Console.WriteLine(element);` на свой MessageBox или что у вас там.

Comment: У меня Windows Form. Понял спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: @SergeyLytvynenko Ну, галку-то я вижу, только объясните всё-таки за что? За linq или за foreach?

Comment: За LINQ. Плохо разбираюсь в нем. Не давно C# изучаю.

Comment: Это вроде лишнее `.Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })`

Comment: `var result = source.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() % 2 != 0).Select(x => x.Key);`
В ответе неверное выражение. Да и можно оптимизировать чтобы не создавать новый анонимный объект (в читаемости не теряем)

Comment: @AGS17 Ага, работает. Только условие должно быть `==`, а не `!=`

Comment: @AK https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnPH0G

Comment: @AK из вопроса "_x4x3x2x1 x4x3x1 x4x2x1 x4x1 x3x2x1 x3x1 x4x3x2x1 должна вывестись эта же строка только без x4x3x2x1_"

Comment: @AGS17 Хм. Попробовал на оригинальной строке `string[] source = "x4x3x2x1 x4x3x1 x4x2x1 x4x1 x3x2x1 x3x1 x4x3x2x1".Split(' ');
` - да, вы правильно указали условие. Спасибо за подсказку!